# Nomad : raw_exec install nginx

Tags: nginx, driver, ubuntu-18.04, nomad

I want to run raw_exec to install an nginx , is this possible? or how can this be done by raw_exec only. since this code will not start/run.

```
job "raw-exec" {
  datacenters = ["dc1"]
  type        = "service"

  group "exec" {
    count = 1

    update {
       max_parallel      = 1
       min_healthy_time  = "10s"
       healthy_deadline  = "5m"
       progress_deadline = "10m"
       auto_revert       = true
     }

    task "raw-exec-test" {
      driver = "raw_exec"

      config {
        command = "/bin/apt"
        args = ["-y", "install", "nginx.service"]
      }

      resources {
        cpu    = 100
        memory = 125
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the output when you run the spec? Note that the `raw_exec` driver is not enabled by default. It has been be explicitly enabled in the Nomad config.

Answer (score 1):

Without a job status it is hard to troubleshoot what's wrong.
`nomad job status raw-exec` would show your job status. It will also show allocations created by the job.
You can check what's wrong with the allocations (set of tasks in a job should be run on a particular node) that Nomad creates by `nomad alloc status YOUR-ALLOC-ID`.

I've run the following Nomad job specification and it worked well on my MacBook.
I ran nomad using `nomad agent -dev` in one terminal window, then created the file test.job in another terminal window and ran `nomad job run test.job` and it installed `htop` software on the MacBook.

```
job "raw-exec" {
  datacenters = ["dc1"]
  type        = "batch"

  group "exec" {
    count = 1

    task "raw-exec-test" {
      driver = "raw_exec"

      config {
        command = "brew"
        args = ["install", "htop"]
      }

      resources {
        cpu    = 100
        memory = 125
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that I've changed job `type` from service to batch. Batch jobs are designed to run once while services should be up and running all the time.  I suppose that you want your `apt install -y nginx` command to run only once. You can [read more about job types here](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/schedulers/).